# How do I check if condition is true and run code? It's not working code below

Tags: javascript

I tried to check if iteam1 is in the array iteamList and then run the code.

```
var itemsLists =  ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4","item5"]; 
if (itemsLists === "item1") {
console.log("Here is iteam 1");} 
else{
console.log("it's not iteam 1");};
```

//output
it's not iteam 1

I was expecting Here is iteam 1

Comment: Why? `itemsLists` is an array, it is not even loosely equal to a string.

Answer (score 0):

A scalar value will never be equal to an array - as you said you need to check if it is **IN** the array. The simplest way is to use array.includes() but arrays also have find and filter methods to search for matches....

```
if (itemsLists.includes('item1')) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to check if this string exists in the list:

```
var itemsLists =  ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4","item5"]; 
if (itemsLists.includes("item1") == true) {
    console.log("item in list");
}
else {
    console.log("item not in list");
}
```

**Output:**

```
"item in list"
```

This should help you with your problem.
**Also**, please try to research and resolve your problem before posting to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `includes` function to check if this string exists in the list:

For example:

```
if (itemsLists.includes("item1")) {
    console.log("Here is item 1");
} else {
    console.log("it's not item 1");
}
```